# Why are Python sets and dictionaries not ordered by default?

Tags: python, data-types, python-3.x, dictionary

I understand the difference between ordered and unordered sets, and I understand why for many purposes, we don't need ordered sets. But all set operations are still possible on ordered sets, and sets have to be stored internally with some order anyway, so why aren't sets ordered by default? Is the performance impact of preserving the order of sets too large?

Comment: Note that the "ordering" of values in an unordered collection may depend more on insertion order and less (if at all) on the values themselves, which isn't an ordering in the sense usually used (which comes from the mathematical term).

Comment: This question may be considered off-topic, as it isn't about developing a particular program but rather language design.

Comment: @outis I wasn't sure as to the correct sub-site, is there another one that you would suggest?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The point is not that the overhead is particularly large, more that it is there *at all*.

Language features must always strike a balance of cost-effectiveness. Dictionaries are absolutely fundamental to Python programming, so it would be very bad for them to be even slightly slower than they have to be just to preserve insertion order, when most of the time you don't need ordering. It was the correct decision to discard the insertion order in return for slightly faster access, and leave order-preserving data structure for special classes. If there was another data structure that could do all that a dict can, and dict was a lesser-used wrinkle of the language, things might look different.

Comment: My counter-argument to that would be: use a more efficient unordered dict datatype for internal dictionaries (just like there's `deque` to optimise performance in certain other contexts) but let the main user-facing dict datatype preserve order.

Comment: Also, am I right in understanding that the CPython implementation of 3.6 does in fact preserve insertion order for dicts?

Answer (score 10):

You are correct that item are store internally with some order, but this internal order is determined by the hash code of the key, which is what allows retrieval to be so fast. So if a set/dict should be ordered, it would need to maintain a separate internal data structure (say an ordered list of keys) for this.

This would of course increase the size. But perhaps worse, it will affect performance. For example removing an item from a set is an O(1) operation, but if it also have to remove the key from an internal ordered list it would become O(n). Such a cost would be disastrous for some applications. Given that it is pretty rare you need an ordered set, such a trade-off is not be worth it for the standard set/dict types.

Answer (score 9):

Your premise is incorrect.  As of Python 3.6, [`dict`s remember their insertion order](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-compactdict).  This was an implementation detail, and was promoted to full language feature in 3.7.  In 3.6, for the specific case of `**kwargs`, order preservation is specifically guaranteed.

Comment: Yes, I wasn't aware of this when I asked the question, since it's not yet a language feature, just an implementation detail in one implementation. But it seems that at least dictionaries will become ordered long-term, and hopefully also sets.

Comment: @oulenz it's no longer an implementation detail, it's required as of Python 3.7

Answer (score 4):

An ordered set is only possible when the elements to be stored have an ordering (i.e. a comparison method) in the first place - but that is not always a given.

The default set/map implementation in most environments nowadays is based on an autoresizing hashtable, which has these advantages:

- faster
- uses less memory
- doesn't require the elements to provide an ordering

> sets have to be stored internally with some order anyway

But this internal order doesn't necessarily have any meaning, nor does it stay the same. Indeed, one property of hashtables that sometimes confounds inexperienced developers is that the iteration order, which *is* based on the internal ordering, can change completely when elements are added (i.e. when a resize is triggered) or between different runs.

Comment: I don't understand your first remark. We don't need a comparison method, the ordering could just be inherited, e.g. from a list or a string literal `{3, 5, 4}`.

Comment: @oulenz inherited still means there is an ordering. What if there simply *is no* ordering, conceptually?

Comment: Why is that relevant? The point is that we can always choose an ordering (as long as we don't allow uncountable sets). Just use the initial internal ordering if no other ordering is available from the context.

Comment: @oulenz: if you don't mind the ordering being meaningless and varying over time, then every set is ordered, because there will be *some* kind of iteration order. But "ordered set" implies that the ordering is semantic for the elements, and that is not always possible. I don't really understand why you want all sets to be ordered.

Comment: "Ordered set" does not imply that the ordering is semantic, just that there is some ordering. Of course I do care that once this ordering is established, it is preserved, unless its contents are modified.

Comment: @oulenz: yes "ordered set" *does* imply that the ordering is semantic. Otherwise, it is not an ordered set, just a regular set on which you impose some artificial external order. But that has nothing to do with the set then.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't aware that implication existed for some people. I simply had in mind a linearly ordered set from mathematics. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order

Comment: @oulenz: that is exactly what I had in mind as well.

Comment: @jameslarge the order relation doesn't have to be unknown to me. If I derive an ordered set from a list, I know exactly what its order is. If I want to ensure a certain order, I can sort the set. But if you don't need the order, you can just ignore it.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt Then you will find that an ordered set is exactly `a regular set on which you impose some artificial [...] order`. Just like the order of a list doesn't have to be 'semantic' in any way, although I am not really sure what you want that term to mean in this context.

Comment: @oulenz, Oh Foo!  I just realized that when you guys say "ordered set" you are talking about _this_ (or something like it): https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ordered-set .  My background is mostly in other programming languages, and that is totally _not_ what I expected "ordered set" to mean.  Sorry.  I've deleted my previous comment.

Comment: @oulenz: mathematically, what you're describing is closer to a sequence or integer index (1st element, 2nd element/element 0, element 1 &c.), rather than an ordering (though you can use a sequence to define an ordering, and an ordered index set induces an ordering on the indexed set).

Comment: ... Just as not all sets have natural orderings, not all data structures have a natural sequence. Consider an unbalanced tree, which could be iterated in various ways (e.g. breadth-first, depth-first), but no one way is *the* way. Forcing an arbitrary iteration sequence is both conceptually empty (as Michael states in his comments) and can impact performance (as stated in other answers).

Comment: @outis mathematically, an ordered set is a set with a binary relation that is antisymmetric, transitive and total, nothing less and nothing more. No 'naturalness' whatever that may mean. As james large points out, implementations of this exist, it's just that they aren't the default at present.

Comment: @oulenz: the point is that in programming, the ordering relation is generally a property of the elements, not of the set, but used in the implementation of the set, typically something tree-based. I still don't get what you actually want and why.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt james large linked to an implementation above (`A MutableSet that remembers its order, so that every entry has an index.`). An ordered dictionary without values. A list with unique elements.

Comment: @oulenz "natural" is a term of art in mathematics, rather than a formal term (though it does show up in some formal definitions, such as "natural join"). Michael gives one way you could define the term: arising from a property of the elements. My point is that, in math, you'd treat what you're talking about (.eg. `a = [3, 0, 2, 1, 4]`) as a sequence, rather than an order, even though a sequence induces an order (`aᵤ<aᵥ ⇔ u < v`) simply because it's not a useful order in math. Similarly, requiring all collection types to have a defined sequence isn't useful (as Michael also states).

Comment: @outis There's often more than one way of doing things in mathematics. Ordered sets are a pretty fundamental part of mathematics, and preserving order is a very common requirement in programming, so there is no reason to introduce other concepts that simply aren't what my original question was about.

Comment: @oulenz: the answer you get isn't always what you're looking for, and when concepts are part of the answer, they're relevant. Since I'm not sure how to put the points about sequences and arbitrary orders vs natural orders in a way that will make sense to you (and comments aren't for discussion), I'm bowing out.

Comment: Debugging and testing are one use-case where preserving insertion order is almost always desirable.  You folks really went down a wormhole for a very simple question... And I still don't know if python 3.7 preserves set insertion order :(

Answer (score 1):

The general idea behind a set or a dictionary is that you plan to be performing a lot of lookup operations.  It is optimized for said lookup operations by using a hash which allows O(1) lookup in most cases.

Order is done using arrays or linked lists and in fact performing operations where order is important, they are optimized for *that* such as appending a value at the end or beginning.

By the nature of these two data structures, neither is optimized for both.  This isn't to say it isn't possible, but it involves both data structures if you want both lookup and order-based operations to be optimized.

So you have this tradeoff between:

lookup operation optimization <=> order-based operations <=> memory usage

The general consensus is that as a programmer, you generally want to optimize for one or the other but not both, and certainly nobody advocates doubling your memory usage when you only need to optimize one of the two.

That said, there *are* implementations with both, or at least in Java, specifically `LinkedHashMap` is both an array and a hash-based dictionary.  Sometimes you may need both, but it is adviced to use `ArrayList` if you only need a list and a `HashMap` if you only need a dictionary.

Comment: Huh? A Java LinkedHashMap is not "both an array and a hash-based dictionary". It's basically a HashMap (i.e. uses an array internally) superimposed with a linked list to allow iteration in insertion order.

Comment: Linear data structures aren't the only ordered data structures; binary trees can also be ordered (such as red-black and AVL trees,). Another operation that can be involved in the trade-off is insertion (arrays are quite efficient in terms of lookup, iteration and memory usage, but slowest when it comes to insertion).